# How to expand parent's height if the last child element's 'margin-top' is smaller than negative height of itself and the parent element

Tags: html, css

Below is the example of the last child element's `margin-top`, which is smaller than negative height of itself. (height: 50px; margin-top: -100px)

If I didn't add `[id=m2]` as the last child element, the parent's height wouldn't “shrink”.

Now, I don't want the parent's height “shrink” and hope it can always expand to the bottom.

Any idea?

```css
#wrap {
    background: black;
    overflow: visible;
}

.m {
    width: 100px;
}

#m1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #F0F;
}

#m2 {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="m" id="m1"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m2"></div>
 </div>
```

**EDIT:**

I want to achieve a basic masonry effect with background color, like below:

```css
#wrap {
    background: black;
    overflow: visible;
}

.m {
    width: 100px;
}

#m1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #F0F;
}

#m2 {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #0FF;
}

#m3 {
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 230px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #F0F;
}

#m4 {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: 340px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #0FF;
}

#m5 {
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #FF0;
}

#m6 {
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #F00;
}

#m7 {
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: 230px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #0F0;
}

#m8 {
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: 340px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #00F;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="m" id="m1"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m2"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m3"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m4"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m5"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m6"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m7"></div>
    <div class="m" id="m8"></div>
 </div>
```

But the parent's height always shrinks while the last element's `margin-top` is smaller than negative height of itself. I know make the parent's `overflow` `auto` can solve this problem, but I don't want to see the scroll bar. I just hope that the parent's height can expand to the bottom automatically. Can anyone solve this problem?

Comment: The purpose of this is for horizontal align of the div? If yes use display inline-block and margin-left only

Comment: No, the purpose is to make “masonry effect”. See EDIT in the question.